# MySqlException was unhandled during insert

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

I am creating a Visual Studios Registration form with MySql and I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution

Any idea what is causing this?

```
MySqlConnection connection;
string cs = @"server=127.0.0.1;userid=root;password=welcome;database=userinfo";
connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
connection.Open();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
string SQL = "INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`, `email`, `passone`, `passtwo`,'lastname','firstname') VALUES (@userid_txt, @email_txt, @passone_txt, @passtwo_txt, @lastname_txt, @firstname_txt)";
command.CommandText = SQL;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid", userid_txt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", email_txt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("passone", passone_txt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("passtwo", passtwo_txt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", lastname_txt);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", firstname_txt);
command.Connection = connection;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

connection.Close();
```

The inner exception states:

> Parameter '@userid_txt' must be defined

Comment: Read (and report) the *full* error message.

Comment: Under view detail and the InnerException tab it's stating "Parameter '@userid_txt' must be defined"

Comment: So there is the problem! Now, *read* the error message closely, and look at the *names of the parameters* used.

Comment: adjusted the values to include the '@' symbol as well still fatal error message saying same thing

Comment: Read the error message again. If it's similar the names are still not correct: `AddWithValue("@thisIsTheQueryParameter", ..)`.

Comment: Appreciate you dealing with that, just had to scrap my original plan and swap to this which is why I am making stupid errors

Comment: Yes I appreciate your help in pointing out what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

When using parameters in statements like:

```
 .. VALUES (@param1, @param2, ...
```

there should be a corresponding Parameters. AddXXX() line that matches the parameter text, e.g.:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", somevalue);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", othervalue);
```

In your case, you have mismatching parameter tags:

```
 .. VALUES (@userid_txt, @email_txt, ...
```

where "userid_txt" needs to be specified in the Parameters collection:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("userid_txt", userid_txt);
```

you have "**userid**" not "**userid_txt**". Same goes for other parameters.